# Adding views with controllers to a view with controller - proper way?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, model-view-controller, uiviewcontroller

I have to add several views (each having own controller) to a main view (with controller). I am following MVC. Should the code to add these subviews be written in view class or controller class? Also, what is proper way,

```
MyViewController1 *myViewController1 = [[MyViewController1 alloc] init];
[myMainViewController.view addSubview:myViewController1.view];
```

Or, some other way?

There is another option - container view controller (with `addChildViewController` method), but that is tough to manage, so I need the simple way.

Comment: @Murali your edit made it harder to read. Please make sure your edits improve posts in a meaningful way :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're adding view controllers to the view of another view controller, then you need to use container containment. You can do that in IB with container views. That makes it easier, than making custom container controllers in code.

Answer (score 0):

The Absolute best way is to maintain ViewControllers according to their functionality (ex. one might be `dashboardView` one might be `settingsView`). Now when moving from one view controller to another is to use `navigationController`.

The practice I follow is to declare one `navigationController` in `appDelegate` when your app starts and then keep reusing this. Example -

```
YourAppDelegate *delegate=(YourAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
MyViewController1 *myVC = [[ FLOHome alloc ]initWithNibName:@"MyViewController1" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[delegate.navigationController pushViewController:myVC animated:NO];
```

This is the absolute best way when dealing with viewControllers. `navigationController` handles whole lot of stuff like memory management, caching views to make them snappy. You could keep pushing viewcontrollers and poping them when you exit from them...

Comment: why do you say hackish? can u suggest another way to maintain a single instance throughout the app? singleton i mean.

Comment: any view controller that inherits from `UIViewController` has a property `navigationController`, which means that if you push all your view controllers on the navigation stack, they will all have access to the same navigation controller by calling `self.navigationController`.

Comment: but from docs `If the receiver or one of its ancestors is a child of a navigation controller, this property contains the owning navigation controller. This property is nil if the view controller is not embedded inside a navigation controller.` so if not used as part of a `navigationViewcontroller`. this property is not valid. If you use it as part of a `navigationController` as written above this field is set by iOS

Comment: When you first present a view controller, you push it on the navigation stack, at which point its `navigationController` property is set to the navigation controller of the presenting view controller.